# Error in in select data from table in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I use this code to select from a table in SQL Server 2008:

```
sqlcomm.CommandText = "select [objId] from [tablename] where href = @href"
```

The type of `href` in my table is `ntext` and I use this code to select:

```
 sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@href", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
 sqlcomm.Parameters["@href"].Value = 'somestring';
 IDataReader reader = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();
```

But it errors:

> *The data types ntext and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator*

When I use `SqlDbType.NText` it have same error. I can't change type of `href` column in my table. When I use `like @href` it works, but I couldn't use `LIKE` because I want to exact match.

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Your parameter type for HREF is NVarChar? This should match the underlying type.

Comment: You **can** use `LIKE` for an `ntext`. Just don't include any wildcards. Not that it matters as this column can't be indexed anyway though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is what it says.  You cannot compare an NTEXT column with a NVarchar parameter.

```
sqlcomm.CommandText="select [objId] from [tablename] where cast(href as nvarchar(max))=@href"
```

[ntext, text, and image (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) have been deprecated for a while now.  Look to convert them to n/varchar(max) and varbinary(max) as soon as practicable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use ntext columns in a where clause in SQL. I'd suggest converting the column in the SQL statement if you  are unable to change the existing column type e.g.CAST(href AS nvarchar(max)).