# Can't delete a row from database with empty value on text-type column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, delete-row, varcharmax

While trying to remove a row from my database in SQL Squirrel I get the following error.

[image]

Now, this happens when the text-type column has value '' (as in empty)
When it has null, there's no error when deleting.

Why is this? Would it help if I convert the column to be of type varchar(max) instead of text and are there any possible dangers in that?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706669/error-in-in-select-data-from-table-in-sql-server/12706694#12706694) is obviously the same or a related problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
An empty string is a string with zero length or no character. Null is absence of data


used delete statement with [text-type column ='' OR text-type column is NULL]
```